# How to render custom Class objects in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

**Solved** Had to render the images globally outside of the draw method. Here's a link to the github if you find this question and are wondering what the solution looks like in the full code. Its a bit too long to post here as an update. [github canvas orbs](https://github.com/sloont/canvas-orbs/blob/main/src/index.js)

**back to the original question:**

I'm trying to render custom Class objects inside an HTML canvas. Doesn't work with class, but the the same data works without class.

Here's the code:

```
import './styles/index.css';

let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var window_height = window.innerHeight;
var window_width = window.innerWidth;

canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 400;

canvas.style.background = "#232a2e"

const convertSVG = (svgid) => {
    const svg = document.getElementById(svgid);

    const xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);

    const svg64 = btoa(xml);
    const b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64, ';

    return b64Start + svg64;
}

class Orb {
    constructor(xpos, ypos, radius, speed, image) {
        this.xpos = xpos;
        this.ypos = ypos;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.image = convertSVG(image);
    }


    draw(context) {
        const img  = new Image();

        img.onload = function() {
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.clip();
            context.drawImage(img, (this.xpos - this.radius), (this.ypos - this.radius), 64, 64);
            context.restore();
        }
        img.src = this.image;

    }
}

const myOrb = new Orb(150, 150, 30, 1, 'javascript-icon');
myOrb.draw(context);
console.log(myOrb);


const img  = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(300, 300, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.clip();
    context.drawImage(img, (300-32), (300-32), 64, 64);
    context.restore();
}
img.src = convertSVG('javascript-icon');
```

Currently it's only displaying the object I draw explicitly at the bottom of the code, and not the object of class Orb.

Here's a screen cap of the canvas:

[current canvas render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLjOu.jpg)

**EDIT: Additionally**, I can generate a class object and draw the orb based on that. Like so:

```
const myOrb = new Orb(300, 300, 30, 1, 'javascript-icon');
const myOrb2 = new Orb(150, 150, 30, 1, 'java-icon');

const img  = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(myOrb.xpos, myOrb.ypos, myOrb.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.clip();
    context.drawImage(img, (myOrb.xpos-myOrb.radius-2), (myOrb.ypos-myOrb.radius-2), 64, 64);
    context.restore();
}
img.src = myOrb.imageSRC;


console.log(myOrb);
console.log(myOrb2);

myOrb2.draw(context);
```

myOrb renders, but myOrb2 which is drawn with the method of the class is not rendered.

Comment: I can;t get your code to work with my svg but looking at it you are decalring a image inside the `draw()`. I would move that outside of the Orb Class. Second it's possible that when myOrb.draw(context) is called the image isn't fully loaded. If that is the case nothing will happen since you have `img.onload` inside of `draw()`. maybe try wrapping the `myOrb.draw(context)` in an onload function and removing that from inside the draw(). Now draw will only be called once the image is loaded. This is provided you move the `new Image` and `img.src` outside of the class.

Comment: Hmm that sounds like a good approach. So wrap the draw in the onload sounds right, but for the image what if eventually I'm going to want say 10 images. Would I then be looking to populate an array of size 10 with 10 new Image() objects?

Comment: Remember to remove the things that aren't relevant from your post's code. A [mcve] goes a _long_ way. Having said that, why are you using `draw = function(context) { ... }` instead of the normal `draw(context) { ... }`, and why do you have an onload but not an onerror? Reduce your code first, and you'll discover it works just fine (e.g. https://jsbin.com/nigecenube/edit?js,output), then build it back up.

Comment: I want to also thank you @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans for your help. Couldn't have done it without you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach to take. Load the images globally and call draw when image is loaded.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var window_height = window.innerHeight;
var window_width = window.innerWidth;

canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 400;

canvas.style.background = "#232a2e"

const img1  = new Image();
img1.src = 'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/javascript-2752148-2284965.png';
const img2 = new Image();
img2.src = 'https://iconape.com/wp-content/png_logo_vector/cib-javascript.png'

class Orb {
    constructor(xpos, ypos, radius, speed, image) {
        this.xpos = xpos;
        this.ypos = ypos;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.image = image;
    }
    draw(context) {
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.clip();
            context.drawImage(this.image, (this.xpos - this.radius), (this.ypos - this.radius), 64, 64);
            context.restore();
    }
}

const myOrb = new Orb(150, 150, 30, 1, img1);
const myOrb2 = new Orb(350, 150, 30, 1, img2);

window.onload = function() {
myOrb.draw(context);
myOrb2.draw(context);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: So I could iterate through an array of images, and on each iteration, load the image, generate new Orb(), then orb.draw()?

Comment: again, why are we using `draw = function(context)` instead of normal class function synax, `draw(context) { ... }`? The basic "drawing on the 2d context" part of the code works perfectly fine when using the right syntax: https://jsbin.com/nigecenube/edit?js,output

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to handle that portion. I updated the code to allow for flexibility in sending an image to the class. See if that what you want.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is right about the function call. It's not needed since a class uses the syntax `draw(context` vice calling a function.

Comment: I actually had made that change locally after the original post. That's a good point. It still doesn't work that way so it's probably an image loading issue. Edited the original post

Comment: Does passing in your images to the class like I've changed it to in the snippet provide you with what you want for loading multiple images via the class?

Comment: it does. let me change to local svgs and see if it still works. Yeah it works perfect! Thanks a million